# How does cin read strings into an object of string class?

Tags: c++, cin, stdstring, istream

Reading some documentation online I found that `istream` class was part of `C++` long before the `string` class was added. So the `istream` design recognizes basic `C++` types such as `double` and `int`, but it is ignorant of the `string` type. Therefore, there are `istream` class methods for processing `double` and `int` and other basic types, but there are no `istream` class methods for processing `string` objects.

My question is if  there are no `istream` class methods for processing `string` objects, why this program works and how ?

```C++
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  std::string str;
  
  std::cin >> str;
  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with the use **operator overloading**. As shown in the below example, you can create your own class and overload `operator>>` and `operator<<`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Number 
{  
    //overload operator<< so that we can use std::cout<<  
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Number& num);
    
    //overload operator>> so that we can use std::cin>>
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Number &obj);

    int m_value = 0;
    
    public:
        Number(int value = 0);    
};

Number::Number(int value): m_value(value)
{ 
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Number& num)
{
    os << num.m_value;
    return os;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Number &obj)
{
    is >> obj.m_value;
    if (is)        // check that the inputs succeeded
    {
        ;//do something
    }
    else
    {
        obj = Number(); // input failed: give the object the default state
    
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
     Number a{ 10 };
     
     std::cout << a << std::endl; //this will print 10
     
     std::cin >> a; //this will take input from user 
    
    std::cout << a << std::endl; //this will print whatever number (m_value) the user entered above

    return 0;
}
```

By overloading `operator>>` and `operator<<`, this allows us to write `std::cin >> a` and `std::cout << a` in the above program.

Similar to the `Number` class shown above, the `std::string` class also makes use of operator overloading. In particular, [`std::string` overloads `operator>>` and `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt), allowing us to write `std::cin >> str` and `std::cout << str`, as you did in your example.

Comment: The question is about `istream` input, but your answer is all about `ostream` output. Even though your answer is correctly, you should expand it to cover what was actually asked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code snippet that in asked question also contained `std::cout<<str;` so i gave answer according to that. Now i have also added(edited) at the end of my answer for `std::cin >> str`. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::string` overload the `>>` and  `<<` operator to return the type `std::istream` and `std::ostream`

How they overload it, you can look in this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) that [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69779958/how-does-cin-read-strings-into-an-object-of-string-class#comment123344615_69779958) gives.

You can create your own class and overload operators, too. Here is an example:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
   int numberOne;
   double numberTwo;
public:
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyClass& myClass);
   friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyClass& myClass);
};
// Since operator<< is a friend of the MyClass class, we can access MyClass's members directly.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyClass& myClass)
{
    out << myClass.numberOne <<  ' ' << myClass.numberTwo;
    return os;
}
// Since operator>> is a friend of the MyClass class, we can access MyClass's members directly.
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyClass& myClass)
{
    in >> myClass.numberOne;
    in >> myClass.numberTwo;

    return in;
}


int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    std::cin >> myClass;
    std::cout << myClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of operator overloading.

In your case, including `<iostream>` will include `<string>`, a specialization of `std::basic_string`. And `std::basic_string` has the [non-member functions `operator<<` and `operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) defined.

Similarly, you can also overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` for your own custom types.

Comment: "*including `<iostream>` will include `<string>`*" - just note that standard headers are *allowed* to include each other, but are not *requred* to. So, if you want to use `std::string` in your code, don't rely on other headers including `<string>` for you, do it yourself in your own code. Same with any other standard type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thx for the fix. Yes good to note that explicitly. I already corrected that a bit in a quick edit after posting by adding "In your case...". (Still me being first and saying what all other answers repeated minutes after me is apparently not good enough an answer...)